# How return a query in Neo4j with graph?

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

My code is a there but I can't see the tab Graph

Please help me, if its possible!

```
MATCH (a1:Article)-->(p:KeyWords)<--(a2:Article)
WHERE a1.id <> a2.id
RETURN a1.title, a2.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph only shows if you're returning nodes. You're returning properties of nodes, but not the nodes themselves. Try returning a1, a2.

Comment: Mark the answer as the answer pls

Comment: I have to wait 3 minutes to do this ;)